# How to retrieve more than two values from the database

Tags: database

I have a login table names **login**
I have written a stored procedure for the login.
Now what i need is while logging,the **POST** value of the particular **emp_name** should be stored in a Session.
can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

just make a session like this (if php)

```
$_SESSION["emp_name"] = $_POST["emp_name"];
```

Comment: SORRY if my question was not clear 
what i wannted to ask is that how to retireve the value inside the post during login using stored procedure 
I have a stored procedure for login where it is checking the username and password